# Is there a way to look up for a new payment address with a given payment address?

Tags: wallet, address, payment

Given a payment address, is it possible to generate or query the blockchain, using `cardano-graphql`, `cardano-cli`, `plutus` or by other means, so as to obtain a new payment address (unused) for the same wallet?

This is to be achieved without requiring the payment verification key of the receiving wallet.

Illustration of my use case:

Say, a third party has a wallet and I was given one of the payment addresses of that wallet, *address1* = `addr1apq...`

Now, I want to obtain an unused payment address, *address2* for this wallet using the *address1* above and make payment to it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you would need a [extended public key](https://help.cointracker.io/en/articles/2645254-what-is-xpub-ypub-zpub-and-utxo) (xPub) for that. You can grab one (account xPub) from Daedalus or derive it using [cardano-addresses](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses).